# The website does not return the image in webscraping but in the browser it appears normally

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have the following problem: when webscraping product images on a website, the website returns that the image is not available, although if you access it directly through the browser, the image appears normally.

Look the code. The page 6 from webscraping doesn´t return all images, while if you ask in browser like: 'https://www.extra.com.br/c?filtro=D53885&utm_source=b2b_livelo&utm_medium=livelo&utm_campaign=livelo_acumulo&page=6', all the images will  appear.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


dic_produtos = {'marca':[], 'preco':[], 'loja':[], 'categ':[], 'link':[], 'foto':[], 'id_cat':[], 'id_loj':[]}

   
url_pag='https://www.extra.com.br/c?filtro=D53885&utm_source=b2b_livelo&utm_medium=livelo&utm_campaign=livelo_acumulo&page=6'
headers = {'User-Agent': "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/107.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"}
executable_path = r'C:\Users\vinig\Downloads\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe'
browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=executable_path)
browser.get(url_pag)
html = browser.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
produtos = soup.find_all('div', class_="sc-5fec12f4-0 cxOoNz sc-f86ccf37-1 esRPia")
    
for produto in produtos:
    marca = produto.find('h3', attrs={'class':"sc-2b5b888e-2 KTGxe"}).text
    if (produto.find('span', attrs={'data-testid':'price-value'})) is not None:
        preco = produto.find('span', attrs={'data-testid':"price-value"}).text
        index_inic = preco.find('R$')
        index_final = preco.find(',')
        preco_liq = preco[index_inic:index_final+3]   
    else: 
        preco = 0.00
    for item in produto.find_all('img'):
        foto = item['src']
    itens = produto.select('a')
    link = [item['href'] for item in itens]
    #link = str('clube.magazineluiza.com.br')+str(link[0])
    link = str(link[0])
    
    if produto.find('span', attrs={'class':"sc-c0914aad-11 bVfueT"})is not None:
        preco_liq = 0.00
    dic_produtos['marca'].append(marca)
    dic_produtos['preco'].append(preco_liq)
    dic_produtos['loja'].append('extra')
    dic_produtos['categ'].append('eletroport')
    dic_produtos['foto'].append(foto)
    dic_produtos['link'].append(link)
    dic_produtos['id_cat'].append('2')
    dic_produtos['id_loj'].append('3')
           

browser.quit()
```

Look the webscraping return image site:

[image]

And the same page in browser returns:

[image]

I've tried to put a sleep time (time.sleep(25)) but without success.

What would I need to do for webscraping to return the images just like in the browser?

Comment: I see you have the request's headers in a variable; does it still not work when you add the headers to the GET request?

Answer (score 0):

Here, I've updated the code and now you can find many more details about a product including the image and its price.

```
import json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver

dic_produtos = {'marca': [], 'preco': [], 'loja': [], 'categ': [], 'link': [], 'foto': [],
            'id_cat': [], 'id_loj': [], 'brand': [], 'rating': [], 'ratingCount': []}

url_pag = 'https://www.extra.com.br/c?filtro=D53885&utm_source=b2b_livelo&utm_medium=livelo&utm_campaign=livelo_acumulo&page=6'

browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get(url_pag)
html = browser.page_source
browser.quit()

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')

products = json.loads(soup.find('script', attrs={"id": "__NEXT_DATA__"}).text)
# print(products['props']['initialState']['search']['results']['products'])
for product in products['props']['initialState']['search']['results']['products']:

    dic_produtos['marca'].append(product['title'])
    dic_produtos['foto'].append(product['image'])
    dic_produtos['link'].append(product['href'])
    dic_produtos['brand'].append(product['brand'])
    dic_produtos['rating'].append(product['rating'])
    dic_produtos['ratingCount'].append(product['ratingCount'])

    dic_produtos['loja'].append('extra')
    dic_produtos['categ'].append('eletroport')
    dic_produtos['id_cat'].append('2')
    dic_produtos['id_loj'].append('3')

produtos_price = soup.find_all('div', class_="sc-5fec12f4-0 cxOoNz sc-f86ccf37-1 esRPia")
for price in produtos_price:
    preco_liq = price.findNext('span', attrs={"data-testid": "price-value"}).text.split()[-1]
    dic_produtos['preco'].append(preco_liq)

print(dic_produtos)
```

output:

```
{'marca': ['Liquidificador Mondial L99-FR Turbo Power Vermelho 500W com 3 Velocidades', 'Panela Elétrica Britânia Multifunções BPE06 Redstone – Vermelha ', 'Aspirador de Pó e Água Vertical Wap Multi Mob 2 em 1 Sem Fio a Bateria Bivolt com Escova e MOP Elétrico', 'Batedeira Britânia Perola N - 200W', 'Panela Elétrica de Arroz Britânia PA10 10 Xícaras - Vermelha/Inox ', 'Cafeteira Expresso Arno Dolce Gusto Genio S Basic Multibebidas - Branca', 'Fritadeira Elétrica Sem Óleo Air Fryer Philco Jumbo Gourmet PFR13P 8,1 Litros – Preta', 'Liquidificador Arno Power Max LN54 Vermelho 1000W com 15 Velocidades', 'Aspirador de Pó Vertical 2 em 1 Philco Ciclone Force 1250W – Preto/Laranja', 'Churrasqueira Elétrica Arno GPRA Mais Sabor e Menos Fumaça com Controle de Temperatura – Preto e Inox', 'Chaleira Mondial Elétrica Pratic Hot com Capacidade 1 Litro CE-07 - Preta', 'Mixer Philips Walita Pro Mix RI2622/8 com 400W', 'Aspirador de Pó Vertical 2 em 1 Mondial AP-30 Turbo Premium 1200W - Vermelho', 'Liquidificador Philco PLQ1550 Turbo 12 Velocidades + Pulsar 1200W - Preto', 'Liquidificador Mondial Power 2 Black L-28 Preto 550W com 2 Velocidades', 'Aspirador de Pó e Água Electrolux Flex FLEXN - 1400w', 'Aspirador de Pó Vertical 2 em 1 Wap Turbo MOB Sem Fio 70W à Bateria Bivolt com Escova Elétrica', 'Mixer Arno Turbomix DUO MX21 200W – Preto ', 'Aspirador de Pó Vertical Philco Power Clean PAS4000V 2000W – Preto/Vermelho', 'Fritadeira com Óleo Philco Deep Fry 1,8L - Inox'], 'preco': ['121,99', '209,99', '619,99', '109,00', '192,99', '449,99', '669,00', '208,00', 'vista', '259,90', '159,90', '289,99', '209,99', '164,90', '89,90', '329,99', '399,90', '124,00', '314,99', '199,90'], 'loja': ['extra', 'extra', 'extra', 'extra', 'extra', 'extra', 'extra', 'extra', 'extra', 'extra', 'extra', 'extra', 'extra', 'extra', 'extra', 'extra', 'extra', 'extra', 'extra', 'extra'], 'categ': ['eletroport', 'eletroport', 'eletroport', 'eletroport', 'eletroport', 'eletroport', 'eletroport', 'eletroport', 'eletroport', 'eletroport', 'eletroport', 'eletroport', 'eletroport', 'eletroport', 'eletroport', 'eletroport', 'eletroport', 'eletroport', 'eletroport', 'eletroport'], 'link': ['https://www.extra.com.br/liquidificador-mondial-l99-fr-turbo-power-vermelho-500w-com-3-velocidades/p/55005447', 'https://www.extra.com.br/panela-eletrica-britania-multifuncoes-bpe06-redstone-vermelha/p/55004623', 'https://www.extra.com.br/aspirador-de-po-e-agua-vertical-wap-multi-mob-2-em-1-sem-fio-a-bateria-bivolt-com-escova-e-mop-eletrico/p/55004722', 'https://www.extra.com.br/batedeira-britania-perola-n-200w/p/1776000', 'https://www.extra.com.br/panela-eletrica-de-arroz-britania-pa10-10-xicaras-vermelha-inox/p/12729736', 'https://www.extra.com.br/cafeteira-expresso-arno-dolce-gusto-genio-s-basic-multibebidas-branca/p/55015213', 'https://www.extra.com.br/fritadeira-eletrica-sem-oleo-air-fryer-philco-jumbo-gourmet-pfr13p-81-litros-preta/p/55004628', 'https://www.extra.com.br/liquidificador-arno-power-max-ln54-vermelho-1000w-com-15-velocidades/p/12262042', 'https://www.extra.com.br/aspirador-de-po-vertical-2-em-1-philco-ciclone-force-1250w-preto-laranja/p/11631609', 'https://www.extra.com.br/churrasqueira-eletrica-arno-gpra-mais-sabor-e-menos-fumaca-com-controle-de-temperatura-preto-e-inox/p/55007930', 'https://www.extra.com.br/chaleira-mondial-eletrica-pratic-hot-com-capacidade-1-litro-ce-07-preta/p/12555154', 'https://www.extra.com.br/mixer-philips-walita-pro-mix-ri2622-8-com-400w/p/55005341', 'https://www.extra.com.br/aspirador-de-po-vertical-2-em-1-mondial-ap-30-turbo-premium-1200w-vermelho/p/55011879', 'https://www.extra.com.br/liquidificador-philco-plq1550-turbo-12-velocidades-pulsar-1200w-preto/p/55027468', 'https://www.extra.com.br/liquidificador-mondial-power-2-black-l-28-preto-550w-com-2-velocidades/p/410903', 'https://www.extra.com.br/aspirador-de-po-e-agua-electrolux-flex-flexn-1400w/p/10266993', 'https://www.extra.com.br/aspirador-de-po-vertical-2-em-1-wap-turbo-mob-sem-fio-70w-a-bateria-bivolt-com-escova-eletrica/p/55004721', 'https://www.extra.com.br/mixer-arno-turbomix-duo-mx21-200w-preto/p/50001117', 'https://www.extra.com.br/aspirador-de-po-vertical-philco-power-clean-pas4000v-2000w-preto-vermelho/p/50005099', 'https://www.extra.com.br/fritadeira-com-oleo-philco-deep-fry-18l-inox/p/12729686'], 'foto': ['https://imgs.extra.com.br/55005447/1xg.jpg?imwidth=292', 'https://imgs.extra.com.br/55004623/1xg.jpg?imwidth=292', 'https://imgs.extra.com.br/55004722/1xg.jpg?imwidth=292', 'https://imgs.extra.com.br/1776000/1xg.jpg?imwidth=292', 'https://imgs.extra.com.br/12729736/1xg.jpg?imwidth=292', 'https://imgs.extra.com.br/55015213/1g.jpg?imwidth=292', 'https://imgs.extra.com.br/55004628/1xg.jpg?imwidth=292', 'https://imgs.extra.com.br/12262042/1xg.jpg?imwidth=292', 'https://imgs.extra.com.br/11631609/1xg.jpg?imwidth=292', 'https://imgs.extra.com.br/55007930/1xg.jpg?imwidth=292', 'https://imgs.extra.com.br/12555154/1xg.jpg?imwidth=292', 'https://imgs.extra.com.br/55005341/1xg.jpg?imwidth=292', 'https://imgs.extra.com.br/55011879/1g.jpg?imwidth=292', 'https://imgs.extra.com.br/55027468/1xg.jpg?imwidth=292', 'https://imgs.extra.com.br/410903/1g.jpg?imwidth=292', 'https://imgs.extra.com.br/10266993/1g.jpg?imwidth=292', 'https://imgs.extra.com.br/55004721/1xg.jpg?imwidth=292', 'https://imgs.extra.com.br/50001117/1xg.jpg?imwidth=292', 'https://imgs.extra.com.br/50005099/1xg.jpg?imwidth=292', 'https://imgs.extra.com.br/12729686/1xg.jpg?imwidth=292'], 'id_cat': ['2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2'], 'id_loj': ['3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3'], 'brand': ['Mondial', 'Britânia', 'Wap', 'Britânia', 'Britânia', 'Arno', 'Philco', 'Arno', 'Philco', 'Arno', 'Mondial', 'Philips Walita', 'Mondial', 'Philco', 'Mondial', 'Electrolux', 'Wap', 'Arno', 'Philco', 'Philco'], 'rating': [4.5, 4.5, 4.5, 4, 5, 5, 5, 4.5, 4.5, 4.5, 5, 5, 4.5, 4.5, 4.5, 4.5, 4.5, 4.5, 4.5, 4.5], 'ratingCount': [57, 23, 23, 41, 101, 273, 39, 509, 775, 52, 161, 21, 90, 29, 274, 111, 34, 48, 20, 68]}
```

Comment: If you could briefly outline or explain the relevant changes that were necessary for successful implementation, it would add value to the answer. no prose, but a few facts would be cool so anybody don't have to muddle through all the code. Would be great, thanks

Comment: Tks @Ajeet Verma, the imagem works fine, but now the price doesn´t work ('0.00'). In 'Produtos' I can´t find more the price information.

Comment: unfortunately,  HTML returned from "requests" does not contain the price information. So  we can combine the data from requests and selenium to get both "image"  and "price".

Comment: @DaviRiani, I've updated the code above and it solves all your problems,  in fact, now you get more details about a product along with other details such as its rating, rating count, brand, etc.